# How to optimize a wavelet transform?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, wavelet, frequency-domain

I am using complex morlet wavelet to estimate frequencies and damping ratios in a 1-D signal. I have done it so far, and the results are accurate enough. Now my question is how can I modify or optimize my method to get better result. like mixing it with other method such as Neural networks or anything else. I know this question is a bit weird But I need to modify my method somehow.
Kind regards.

Comment: This question is too broad and vague.  What would you consider a "better result"?  What's lacking in the current results?

Comment: @endolith Hi, I have few close mode in a signal. like [0.3,0.7,1 Hz]. and each mode has its damping ratio.with selecting a good fb and fc I have got almost accurate result. but the estimation has better result around fc. so as a first step how can I change fc automatically in a smart manner to get very accurate result for all modes? on the other hand I understand that By selecting a low value for fb some Highly damped modes are vanished in my output, so also I would like to know if there is a precise relationship that connect Fb to damping ratio? Tnx

Comment: @endolith , Imagine I want to have only modes with less than 5% damping ratio in my result then what fb must be? 
also is it possible to apply any optimization method on complex morlet method?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but you should edit the question and add those details.  it would be best to show a plot or data to indicate what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: @endolith , thanks for your attention. I am not a signal processing expert. that's why question are not clear usually and I am not getting an answer for them most of the time.but I am learning a lot in this forum. tnx